# How to check whether the logged user is equal to the case.ownerId in LWC component JS file

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I am new to LWC components and struggling to do this check. Below is my code. Please help me where am i going wrong

```
import { api, LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import USERID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import CASE_OWNERID from '@salesforce/schema/Case.OwnerId';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

@api restrictCompose = false;
@api userId;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [CASE_OWNERID] })
    case;
    ownerId;
    userId = USERID;
    wiredRecord({error,data}){
        if (data) {
            this.case = data;
            this.ownerId = this.case.fields.ownerId.value;
        }

    }
  get enableCompose(){
        console.log('ownerId: '+this.ownerId );
        console.log('userId: '+this.userId );
            if(userId == ownerId){
                this.restrictCompose = true;
            } 
            console.log('enableCompose: '+this.restrictCompose );
        return restrictCompose;
    }
```

**html file:**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-publisher slds-publisher_comment slds-is-active">
        <lightning-textarea placeholder="TextMsg" label="messaging input"
            class="slds-publisher__input slds-input_bare slds-text-longform" value={msgbody}  disabled={enableCompose}></lightning-textarea> 
</div>
</template>
```

Thanks,
Lakshmi

Comment: Don't mess with declaration order. `@wire(...)` should be followed by `wiredRecord(...`, it can't work if you put things in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never defined a `recordId` property decorated with `@api`, moreover you decorated the property `case`, not `wiredRecord` function, so the latter will never run.
Finally in the `enableCompose` getter the if condition checks undefined variables since you forgot `this` keyword. It also would return undefined due to the same reason (`restrictCompose` and `this.restrictCompose` are not the same).
Anyway the getter could be removed and `restrictCompose` could be setted in the `wiredRecord` function.

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import USERID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import CASE_OWNERID from '@salesforce/schema/Case.OwnerId';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

// Replace ComponentName with the correct value
export default class ComponentName extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    restrictCompose = false;
    userId = USERID;
    msgbody;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [CASE_OWNERID] })
    wiredRecord({error, data}){
        if (data) {
            const onwerId = getFieldValue(data, CASE_OWNERID);
            console.log('onwerId:', onwerId, ' - userId:', this.userId);
            this.restrictCompose = onwerId == this.userId;
        } else if (error) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, fields used in HTML are already reactive, there is no need to decorate them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working for me.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this? and again why you not check at your wire service result?

```
  get enableCompose(){        
     return (this.userId && this.ownerId && this.userId === this.ownerId)? true ; false;         
   }


@track enableCompose = false;
 wiredRecord({error,data}){
    if (data) {
        this.case = data;
        this.enableCompose = (this.case.fields.ownerId.value === this.userId)? true : false;
    }

}
```